# Is intel-virtual-output a saviour tool?

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

What I mean is that can this be used to solve the eternal problem of hybrid graphcs laptop + external monitor? Can this be used to power an external display in Hybrid Graphics mode? Also, are there any caveats in using this, as in performance?

To explain a little a further, I'm using an HP gaming laptop that's unfortunately an nVidia Optimus laptop. As a result, the HDMI output is wired to the nVidia discrete GPU; meaning I can't use my Intel iGPU to power my external monitor. Even if I use a USB Type-C to HDMI cable, the Intel iGPU can't recognize my monitor. Afer months of desperation, I found this potential solution, but unfortunatrly, it seems like a lot of people don't know much about it.

If this doesn't work, I guess I'll have to return to Windows. nVidia is really, such a b-word.

Comment: All is wrong. The HDMI is not "wired" to Nvidia. It doesn't work this way. Please [edit] your question and explain the real problem including which Ubuntu release is used, which Nvidia drivers, and what is happening.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that the HDMI is wired to Nvidia. I've read that manufacturers of gaming laptops themselves do this because the Intel GPU cannot support more than 2 external monitors. So, for better multi-monitor support, they wire the HDMI port to the discrete graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this by yourself.

Documents to read more about the `intel-virtual-output`:

- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man4/intel-virtual-output.4.html
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bumblebee#Output_wired_to_the_NVIDIA_chip

Using `mate-optimus` on Ubuntu MATE [may help](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-focal-fossa-release-notes/) too.